# Better way to validate fields using function php

Tags: php

For validation the for given field i written function like this. Please review and improve my function to project worthy

my field

```
try{
    $message = 'First Name accepts keyboard characters only.';
    doValidateField ( $firstName, 'First Name', true, 100, '/^([a-zA-Z0-9._\- #,^&`~<>:!@$(){}\"\';\*\[\]?%| \n \r \t]*)$/', $message );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage ();
    echo $errorMessage;
}
```

function

```
/*
* The following function is validates the fields
* @params unknown values $fieldValue, $fieldName, $required, $maxLength, $mask, $message
* @return tables rows $rowResponse
*/

function doValidateField($fieldValue, $fieldName, $required, $maxLength, $mask, $message) {
    // Checking the required field is empty or not
    if ($required) {
        if (strlen ( $fieldValue ) <= 0) {
            throw new Exception ( $fieldName . " is required." );
        }
    }

    // Check field length is not greater than allowed length
    if (strlen ( $fieldValue ) > $maxLength) {
        throw new Exception ( $fieldName . " cannot be greater than " . $maxLength . " characters." );
    }

    // check if specified mask exists in the field
    if (! (preg_match ( $mask, $fieldValue ))) {
        throw new Exception ( $message );
    }

}
```

Comment: "better" in which sense? Can you point out which problems you see with the current version?

Comment: Is something not working? Or maybe you're looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You should write more specific functions (smaller, easier functions), like IsEmail(), IsStrLen(). All you need to do then is to "loop" through all your tests and call the according smaller function.

Comment: So Émile, Jörg, Björk, Józef and Ángel are not allowed to enter thier own names?

Comment: This is not php validation but javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit less-specific than the answer you want, but I would suggest you take at look at some of the patterns and ideas used by the [Zend_Validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html) classes. (It says "Zend", but it is not a default part of PHP.)

On that note:

- I wouldn't throw exceptions. It makes it easier to find the first problem, but harder to loop through multiple validators. Typically you'll want to show people *all* the places they made an error, rather than showing only the first problem and making them repeatedly submit the form to work their way through them all.
- Don't make a validation function, make a validation class. Basically, use OOP. Not only does it make for cleaner and easier-to-improve code, but you can make copies of the validator and tweak their rules/messages slightly as necessary.
- Remember that things get a little weird when you start dealing with accented characters or different languages. Figure out whether the thing you are building needs extra work for that or not.